# Column in latest go-pg

Tags: go, go-pg

I am updating from go-pg from `8.0.5` to `10.3.2` and I am having a problem with the columns ORM

structures:

```
type Item struct {
    ID   int    `pg:"id,pk"`
    Name string `pg:"name"`
    Desc string `pg:"description"`

    SubItems []SubItem `pg:"rel:has-many"`
}

type SubItem struct {
    ID     int    `pg:"id,pk"`
    ItemID int    `pg:"item_id"`
    Name   string `pg:"name"`

    Item Item `pg:"rel:has-one"`
}
```

and this is the section of the unit test that is failing

```
list := []test.Item{{ID: 1, Name: "first"}, {ID: 2, Name: "second"}, {ID: 3, Name: "third"}}
subItems := []test.SubItem{{ID: 1, ItemID: 1}, {ID: 2, ItemID: 3}}

_, err := dbConn.model(list).Insert()
So(err, ShouldBeNil)
_, err = dbConn.model(subItems).Insert()
So(err, ShouldBeNil)

expected := test.SubItem{
    ID:     2,
    ItemID: 3,
    Item:   test.Item{ID: 3, Name: "third"},
}

var actual test.SubItem

err = dbConn.Model(&actual).Column("item").Where("sub_item.id = 2").Select()
So(err, ShouldBeNil)
So(actual, ShouldResemble, expected)
```

The problem I am running into is, in v8, this selected `item` with a join.  In v10, it's throwing a "column 'item' does not exist" error.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is changed in v9 check [changes here](https://pg.uptrace.dev/changelog/):

> Query.Column does not accept relation name any more. Use Query.Relation instead which returns an error if relation does not exist.

Try with ***Relation*** then you get all the Item columns.

```
err = dbConn.Model(&actual).
    Column("_").
    Relation("Item").
    Where("sub_item.id = 2").
    Select()
```

There are more select options with mappings of table relations in docs: [Writing queries](https://pg.uptrace.dev/queries/)